# Google cloud build fails

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gitlab, adonis.js, adonisjs-ace

I have an adonis app that I'm trying to deploy to google cloud by mirroring a gitlab repo. I have my cloudbuild.yaml files set up and have deployed different builds of this app in the past but for some reason now I get this error when trying to build.

cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
  # Install node.js dependencies
  - name: node
    entrypoint: npm
    args: ["install"]
  # Fetch gcp-service-account.json from storage
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
    args:
      [
        "cp",
        "gs://api-vampfi-deployment-files/deployment-files/gcp-service-account.json",
        "gcp-service-account.json",
      ]
  # Fetch environment variables from storage
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
    args:
      [
        "cp",
        "gs://api-vampfi-deployment-files/deployment-files/${_ENV}.env",
        ".env",
      ]
  # Fetch app.yaml from storage
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
    args:
      [
        "cp",
        "gs://api-vampfi-deployment-files/deployment-files/${_ENV}.yaml",
        "app.yaml",
      ]
  # Run Migrations
  - name: node
    entrypoint: node
    args: ["ace", "migration:run", "--force"]
  # Run Seeders -- Resource heavy, enable only when neccesary
  - name: node
    entrypoint: node
    args: ["ace", "seed", "--files", "DatabaseSeeder.js", "--force"]
  # Deploy application
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
    args: ["app", "deploy"]
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "vamp",
  "version": "4.1.0",
  "adonis-version": "4.1.0",
  "description": "Rethink Facility Management",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "adonis serve --dev",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "node ace test",
    "seed": "node ace seed --files \"DatabaseSeeder.js\" --force",
    "update-env": "gsutil -m cp -r tmp/deployment-files gs://api-vampfi-deployment-files"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "adonisjs",
    "adonis-app"
  ],
  "author": "Obapelumi - Filmo Product Dev",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@adonisjs/ace": "^5.0.8",
    "@adonisjs/auth": "^3.0.7",
    "@adonisjs/bodyparser": "^2.0.5",
    "@adonisjs/cors": "^1.0.7",
    "@adonisjs/fold": "^4.0.9",
    "@adonisjs/framework": "^5.0.9",
    "@adonisjs/ignitor": "^2.0.8",
    "@adonisjs/lucid": "^6.1.3",
    "@adonisjs/mail": "^3.0.9",
    "@adonisjs/validator": "^5.0.6",
    "@adonisjs/websocket": "^1.0.12",
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^2.5.0",
    "@radmen/adonis-lucid-soft-deletes": "^0.1.2",
    "adonis-google-cloud-storage": "^1.0.0",
    "adonis-scheduler": "^3.0.2",
    "africastalking": "^0.4.4",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "mime": "^2.4.4",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "mqtt": "^3.0.0",
    "mssql": "4.1.0",
    "mysql": "^2.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "standard": "^13.1.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "App": "./app"
  },
  "prettier": {
    "trailingComma": "none"
  }
}
```

error from cloud build

```
ERROR: build step 0 "node" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
ERROR
Finished Step #0
Step #0: npm ERR!     /builder/home/.npm/_logs/2021-01-23T19_33_14_163Z-debug.log
Step #0: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
Step #0: 
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v15.6.0
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /workspace/node_modules/grpc
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.0-1029-gcp
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:285:12)
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:379:20)
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp: Undefined variable module_path in binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/workspace/node_modules/grpc',
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/builder/home/.cache/node-gyp/15.6.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/builder/home/.cache/node-gyp/15.6.0',
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/builder/home/.cache/node-gyp/15.6.0/include/node/common.gypi',
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/workspace/node_modules/grpc/build/config.gypi',
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.6.0/SHASUMS256.txt
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.6.0/SHASUMS256.txt
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.6.0/node-v15.6.0-headers.tar.gz
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.6.0/node-v15.6.0-headers.tar.gz
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.5.3 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp info using node@15.6.0 | linux | x64
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
Step #0: npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
Step #0: npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp rebuild
Step #0: npm ERR! command failed
Step #0: npm ERR! path /workspace/node_modules/grpc
Step #0: npm ERR! code 1
Step #0: docker.io/library/node:latest
Step #0: Status: Downloaded newer image for node:latest
Step #0: Digest: sha256:ebf5158e91b303bd93e77537065742c42657aa7ca1714ada7cedee3e2033191f
Step #0: c57d0532f0ca: Pull complete
Step #0: 2ab9800d7323: Pull complete
Step #0: 856f8ebc161d: Pull complete
Step #0: dd25ee3ea38e: Pull complete
Step #0: 00e912dd434d: Pull complete
Step #0: ed36dafe30e3: Pull complete
Step #0: d4d3f270c7de: Pull complete
Step #0: 953fe5c215cb: Pull complete
Step #0: 2587235a7635: Pull complete
Step #0: 00e912dd434d: Download complete
Step #0: 00e912dd434d: Verifying Checksum
Step #0: 856f8ebc161d: Download complete
Step #0: 856f8ebc161d: Verifying Checksum
Step #0: c57d0532f0ca: Download complete
Step #0: c57d0532f0ca: Verifying Checksum
Step #0: 2ab9800d7323: Download complete
Step #0: 2ab9800d7323: Verifying Checksum
Step #0: dd25ee3ea38e: Download complete
Step #0: dd25ee3ea38e: Verifying Checksum
Step #0: ed36dafe30e3: Download complete
Step #0: ed36dafe30e3: Verifying Checksum
Step #0: 2587235a7635: Download complete
Step #0: 2587235a7635: Verifying Checksum
Step #0: 953fe5c215cb: Download complete
Step #0: 953fe5c215cb: Verifying Checksum
Step #0: d4d3f270c7de: Download complete
Step #0: d4d3f270c7de: Verifying Checksum
Step #0: c57d0532f0ca: Waiting
Step #0: 2ab9800d7323: Waiting
Step #0: 856f8ebc161d: Waiting
Step #0: dd25ee3ea38e: Waiting
Step #0: 00e912dd434d: Waiting
Step #0: ed36dafe30e3: Waiting
Step #0: c57d0532f0ca: Pulling fs layer
Step #0: 2ab9800d7323: Pulling fs layer
Step #0: 856f8ebc161d: Pulling fs layer
Step #0: dd25ee3ea38e: Pulling fs layer
Step #0: 00e912dd434d: Pulling fs layer
Step #0: ed36dafe30e3: Pulling fs layer
Step #0: d4d3f270c7de: Pulling fs layer
Step #0: 953fe5c215cb: Pulling fs layer
Step #0: 2587235a7635: Pulling fs layer
Step #0: latest: Pulling from library/node
Step #0: Using default tag: latest
Step #0: Pulling image: node
Starting Step #0
BUILD
HEAD is now at be1b1b0 updated package.json
 * branch            be1b1b0c720285fae283e87ca7dfc1e9c81dd2cc -> FETCH_HEAD
From https://source.developers.google.com/p/vampfi-c5b1c/r/api.vampfi
Initialized empty Git repository in /workspace/.git/
FETCHSOURCE

starting build "9d616543-3e89-448e-95d8-77f111b241ec"
```

Please help.

Comment: Did you checked `npm ERR! gyp: Undefined variable module_path in binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp`?

Comment: Based on your first step, Cloud Build will use the latest Node version. Have you tried specifying the Node version (**ex.** `node:12`)?